Processing large dottrace snapshots
I have an apporx 16.4 GB snapshot that I am trying to open via dottrace and it keeps getting stuck at processing events at 80%, seems like its hitting very high memory utilisation on my machine. Are there alternative tools that can do such large snapshots or are there ways to load partially?
Anything people have tried and succeded with really large trace snapshots?
